# elif and list index out of range - Python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, indexing

Essentially my code refines an array. If the next bit of data along is too far away it searches the above and below index to see if that piece of data is better suited to be in its index, i.e.

```
def distance(x, y):
    if x > y:
        result = x - y
    else:
        result = y - x
    return result


for y in range(0,10):
    for x in range(0,10):
        newarray[y][0] = myarray[y][0]
        if distance(myarray[y][x],myarray[y][x+1]) > myerror:
            if distance(myarray[y-1][x+1],newarrayarray[y][x]) <= myerror:
                newarray[y][x+1] = myarray[y-1][x+1]
            elif distance(myarray[y-2][x+1],newarrayarray[y][x]) <= myerror:
                newarray[y][x+1] = myarray[y-2][x+1]
            elif distance(myarray[y+1][x+1],newarrayarray[y][x]) <= myerror:
                newarray[y][x+1] = myarray[y+1][x+1]
            elif distance(myarray[y+2][x+1],newarrayarray[y][x]) <= myerror:
                newarray[y][x+1] = myarray[y+2][x+1]
            else:
                newarray[y][x+1] = myarray[y][x+1]
        else:
            newarray[y][x+1] = myarray[y][x+1]
```

So this code works very well for specific values of y, more specifically the middle values of the array. THe problem I have is the outer values because obviously for y=10 there is no y+1 value.

What I want to happen is if it goes out of the index range I want it to just treat it as not meeting my set condition rather than seeing it as an error. So when y=10, when it looks for y=11 rather than throwing a hissy fit because it doesn't exist I want it to just say no this isn't true move on to the next if.

I hope this makes sense, please comment if it doesn't and I'll try to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is, before you do the distance calculation in each if, to check if the adjacent x or y value you want to test is in range, with a logical and  between that and the distance check.  Since it uses lazy evaluation, if the first condition fails, it will never evaluate the second, and you'll never get an error.

Comment: The logical 'and' in Python is `and`.

Comment: While this is a better structure, it still doesn't solve the problem of when the first condition passes but the second condition throws up the error. Essentially there is always a scenario where the first distance is out of range but the next index doesn't exist. The only way to get around this is to disallow the outside indices from running in the code.

What I'd prefer to do is have a condition where it requires that index to exist and then do the other condition.